# parse generic sealed class in kotlin using jackson

Tags: json, kotlin, jackson

I have the following generic sealed class representing the status of network response.

```kotlin
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "status")
@JsonSubTypes(
    value = [
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Response.OK::class, name = "OK"),
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Response.Error::class, name = "ERROR"),
    ]
)
sealed class Response<out Content, out Error> {
    data class OK<out Content>(val content: Content) : Response<Content, Nothing>()
    data class Error<out Error>(val error: Error) : Response<Nothing, Error>()
}
```

The network response json can have `status": "OK"` in which case it contains a `content` key or a  `"status": "ERROR"` in which case it contains a `error` key.

The type under the `content` and `error` key can be different for each endpoint I’m talking to. Hence the need for generic types

So for example one endpoit returns `String` as types, so `Response<String, String>`

```json
{
  "status": "OK",
  "content": "Hello"
}
```

```json
{
  "status": "ERROR",
  "error": "MyError"
}
```

Another endpoit return `Double` as content and `Int` as error, so

`Response<Double, Int>`

```json
{
  "status": "OK",
  "content": 2.0
}
```

```json
{
  "status": "ERROR",
  "error": 1
}
```

My parsing fails though with message

```
Could not resolve type id 'OK' as a subtype of `com.example.models.Response<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>`: Failed to specialize base type com.example.models.Response<java.lang.String,java.lang.String> as com.example.models.Response$OK, problem: Type parameter #1/2 differs; can not specialize java.lang.String with java.lang.Object
 at [Source: (String)"{
  "status": "OK",
  "content": "Hello"
}"; line: 2, column: 13]
```

```kotlin
@Nested
inner class ContentParsingTests {
    @Test
    fun `parses OK response`() {
        val json = """
    {
      "status": "OK",
      "content": "Hello"
    }
    """.trimIndent()

        when (val result = objectMapper.readValue<Response<String, String>>(json)) {
            is Response.OK -> {
                assertEquals(result.content, "Hello")
            }
            is Response.Error -> {
                fail()
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun `parses ERROR response`() {
        val json = """
        {
          "status": "ERROR",
          "error": "MyError"
        }
    """.trimIndent()

        when (val result = objectMapper.readValue<Response<String, String>>(json)) {
            is Response.OK -> {
                fail()
            }
            is Response.Error -> {
                assertEquals(result.error, "MyError")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed that the parsing works fine if only the content is generic:

```kotlin
sealed class Response<out Content > {
    data class OK<out Content>(val content: Content) : Response<Content>()
    object Error : Response<Nothing>()
}
```

but of course I loose the error payload

What would be a correct way to parse the json into my generic class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with `Nothing` because it's like `Void` and you can't create an instance of it or get a type information that's why the serialization library struggling with it. so a solution for the current problem is to update the model definition like this and it works. It's not ideal though.

```kotlin
sealed class Response<out Content, out Error> {

    data class OK<out Content, out Error>(val content: Content) : Response<Content, Error>()

    data class Error<out Content, out Error>(val error: Error) : Response<Content, Error>()
}
```

Comment: great, thanks!. It parses correctly and at the callsite the usage of the `Response<SomeType, SomeOtherType>` remains the same so that works for me :)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need generics at all for this case. Just have:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "status")
@JsonSubTypes(
    value = [
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Response.OK::class, name = "OK"),
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Response.Error::class, name = "ERROR"),
    ]
)
sealed interface Response {
  data class Success(val content: Content): Response
  data class Error(val error: Error): Response
}
```

Jackson will then be able to parse everything correctly.

Comment: I’m not sure to understand. What would be the type of `Content` and `Error` if it’s not generic? How would I achieve the parsing of different content and error types?